# Transparency/Opacity-What is the easiest way to make an object partially transparent without shaders?

Tags: transparency

What is the easiest way to make an object partially transparent without shaders? It looks like the Transparency checkbox from the Viewport Display area has been moved/removed in version 2.8.2a...

I've followed several tutorials, changing the alpha channel of the Material's Base Color in the Material Properties tab, Viewport Display, toggling between the Material and Object Color selector in the Viewport Shading window, etc. Enabling Alpha Blend or Alpha Clip, to no avail. I've tried both Eevee and Cycles.

Whatever I try, as I drag the alpha value, the object will instantly disappear completely at a certain point, like a clipping level has just been passed. I cannot get a partial transparency/opacity.

I am just trying this with basic Cube mesh objects, and just looking for the simplest method for creating partially transparent objects in the Viewport and when rendered.